# Javascript static file not loading on pythonanywhere django website

Tags: python, html, django, pythonanywhere, django-staticfiles

Even though css static file loads, js codes in static folder refused to load even after I included the path on the web tab, all solutions I saw on pythonanywhere forum are all css centered. the weird part is after using developer tools i see css codes inside the js file in source instead of the actual js code.
jsscripts.js:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#buttonOne', function(){
  $.ajax({
   url: 'add-friend/',
   data: {
   'serializedVal': $(this).attr("value")
   },
   type: "GET",
   success: function(response) {
   $("#buttonOne").hide();
   alert("friend request has been sent successfully");
   }
  });

 });


$(document).on('click', '#buttonTwo', function(){
  $.ajax({
   context: this,
   url: '/friends/accept-requests-detail/',
   data: {
   'serializedVall': $(this).attr("value")
   },
   type: "GET",
   success: function(response) {
   $(this).hide();
   alert("friend request has been added successfully");
   }
  });

 });

 $(document).on('click', '#liked', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   context: this,
   url: '/posts/like/',
   data: {
   'serializedVall': $(this).attr("value")
   },
   type: "GET",
   success: function (json) {
  $('.far').removeClass('far').addClass('fas');
  $('.fa-heart').css('color','red')
  $('#NumLike').css('color','red')
  $('#NumLike').html(json['result']);
  console.log(json);

   }
  });

 });



 $(document).on('click', '.posts', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
   context: this,
   url: '/posts/like/',
   data: {
   'serializedVall': $(this).attr("value")
   },
   type: "GET",
   success: function (json) {

  $(this).removeClass(json['odd']).addClass(json['lat'])
  $(this).css('color',json['col'])
  $(this).html(json['result'])




  console.log(json);
   }
  });

 });
```

base.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'posts/main.css' %}">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Django Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
      <div class="navbar">
  <a href="{% url 'posts-home'%}"><i class="fa fa-home hicon"></i></a>
  <a href="{% url 'friends-search' %}"><i class="fa fa-search hicon"></i></a>
  {% if NumOfMessages == 0 %}
<a href="{% url 'chatt' %}"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope hicon"></i></span> </a>
  {% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'chatt' %}"><span><i class="fa fa-envelope hicon"></i></span><span class="badge">{{ NumOfMessages }}</span> </a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if NumOfNotifications == 0 %}
<a href="{% url 'notifications' %}"><span><i class="fa fa-globe hicon"></i></span> </a>
  {% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'notifications' %}"><span><i class="fa fa-globe hicon"></i></span><span class="badge">{{ NumOfNotifications }}</span> </a>
  {% endif %}
  <a href="{% url 'profile' %}"><i class="fa fa-user-circle hicon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
    </header>
    <main role="main" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
              <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message }}
              </div>
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer src="{% static 'posts/jsscripts.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this the url to inspect it in developers tool https://preciousdon.pythonanywhere.com

Comment: Did you follow this formula `{% load static %}<script defer src="{% static 'js file' %}"></script>`

Comment: i didn't add defer in the tag though

Comment: Defer inside script tags make it run when the page loads.

Comment: still the same even after hard reload, the most annoying part is why it's actually showing css codes that are in the main.css file in the js file instead of the js code i wrote when i check sources in developers tools

Comment: Can you include some source code?

Comment: i've edited the post to add source code

Comment: Did you add "'django.contrib.staticfiles'" in the INSTALLED_APPS of settings.py?

Comment: yes its there with STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL specified in settings.py

Comment: Check devtools console for errors.

Comment: i checked already the only error there is that it placed css codes originally in the main.css into the js file in the source section of developers tools

Comment: It looks like you're overriding /static/ mapping by path to css file. Every url preciousdon.pythonanywhere.com/static/... loads the css file. How are your static files mappings on the PA Web page looking like? Do you have multiple mappings of /static/?